# No route matches "#show" for "#new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I've come across a strange routing issue that I am not sure how to solve.

I have a route that looks like...

```
new_tenants_venue GET  /tenants/venues/new(.:format)  tenants/venues#new
```

but when I hit that route, "/tenants/venues/new", I get the error...

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"tenants/venues", ...
```

I don't see any similar routes in the list that would interfere, especially before that route. After it comes the #show route but that has an :id rather than "new"

Comment: Well, it looks like its taking "new" as the id of "show", which is indeed weird. Can you post your routes and your controller?

Comment: What is the output when you execute `rake routes` in terminal?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=2M56H6BW

Comment: you hit that route by insert url in address browser?

Comment: yes, so on my local machine http://0.0.0.0:3000/tenants/venues/new

Answer (score 0):

So, I made a classic noob mistake and didn't check the partial I included in the view. On one of the link_to paths I had a singular/plural mistake in the the name. It seemed as if it was the route that was causing the issue. Damn rails error codes!